# Full webpart SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part

How can I create a full webpart , that i can import in SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you require this web part to do?

You can create Data View Web Parts in SharePoint Designer 2007, which you can "Export" via the Web Interface. This produces a .webpart file which you can upload into the Site Web Part Gallery.

If you require more complex functionality you will need to produce a .NET assembly which will need to be deployed by a server administrator.

Whichever method you choose is dependant on the business requirement for your web part.

Comment: Thanks James, can you tell me how the date view webpart can be done ?

Comment: You need SharePoint Designer 2007 installed first, then you can follow one of the many tutorials available on sites such as endusersharepoint.com for creating Data View Web Parts. Which method you use depends entirely on the list data source you're presenting.

Answer (score 0):

See this [CodeGuru article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c12293) or this one from [SharePoint-Girl](http://www.sharepoint-girl.com/2008/02/wss-web-part-tutorial.html).

More on [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+webpart+tutorial).

Comment: this is good info, but what i need is how to create a webpart that is ready just to be uploaded to sharepoint site, through import webpart, which can be done even as a site admin, not a server admin ?